# extending a class AND comparable in a generic java data structure

Tags: java, tree, extends, comparable

For homework I was assigned to make an AVL Tree data structure.
I am trying to make my "add" method to add a piece of generic data to the tree.
My problem is that in the assignment we must extend a class that was given to us called "BinaryTree".
Within my add method I need to use the compareTo method, which I believe means that I also have to Extend Comparable.
I have looked online and apparently you cannot extend two classes so this becomes a problem. I decided to try to write my own compareTo method in my AVL tree class but it says the < and > cannot be applied to my generic type.
Any hints or quick workarounds? or am I just being dumb?

Thanks
 - Steve

Comment: In order to address the generics problem you're having it would be helpful to see a snippet of the code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Generics to specify the type and require that it implements Comparable. That way you have access to both the type and compareTo() within the AVL Tree.

```
public class AVL<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinaryTree {

    public void add(T object) {
            ...
        object.compareTo(some other object)
            ...
    }
}
```

Then you would create it as `AVL<MyObject> avl = new AVL<MyObject>()`

Answer (score 3):

Java does not support multiple inheritance. However, you do not need to *extend* Comparable, you need to *implement* Comparable. [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is an interface. You do not extend an interface, you implement it.

Hope this helps.

An example below:-

`public final class AVL implements Comparable<SomeObject> extends BinaryTree`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `java.lang.Comparable` is an interface, not a class.  Java only allows you to extend one class, but you can implement as many interfaces as you like, so it's perfectly valid to do something like this:

```
public class MyTreeImpl extends BinaryTree implements Comparable<MyTreeImpl> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyTreeImpl o) {
        // your compare implementation
    }

    // the rest of your class definition
}
```

To address your issue with generics I think I'd need to see your code and the exact error the compiler was giving you.

Answer (score 0):

You normally want to compare the keys in your tree with each other, not one tree with another one, or to a key.

Thus, your *key objects* should implement `Comparable`, or better `Comparable<K>` where `K` is some supertype of your keys.

This normally means that you would declare your AVLTree class to be generic:

```
class AVLTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> extends BinaryTree {

   ...

}
```

I did not really understand the relation to your BinaryTree class, sorry.